# Need to search a file for specific terms and output the second term into a csv with repetition - Python

Tags: python, csv, oop, text

I am trying to read a text file that uses ":" as the delimiter, find specific search terms in the first column, and output the second column to a .csv file.

The file I'm pulling from has multiple sections that look like this (showing 2 rows of many):

```
 Object : Info1
   Type : Info2
   LastChange : INFO3
   DeviceId : INFO4
EndObject

Object : Info5
   Type : Info6
   LastChange : INFO7
   DeviceId : INFO8
EndObject
```

and this repeats with the same first column (object, type..etc) but different Info#

I want to search through and pull the 'Info#' into a csv file to read out as:
Info1,Info2,Info3,Info4 by searching the first column there (Object Type LastChange DeviceId)

So far I have gotten it to output object & type, but the for loop I have only does one iteration, my code so far:

```
import csv
import string
import pandas as pd


        

filename1 = 'test.txt'                      #EDIT THIS TO MATCH EXACTLY THE .DMP FILE YOU WISH TO READ!!

infile = open(filename1, 'r', errors = 'ignore')                    #this names the read file variable, !!DO NOT TOUCH!!             
lines = infile.readlines()

        
filename2 = 'test.csv'                    
outfile = open(filename2,'w')
headerList ="Type:Device:Name:Change\n".split(':')     
headerString = ','.join(headerList)
outfile.write(headerString)
for line in lines[1:]:
       sline = line.split(":")                    

       if  'Type' in sline[0]:
        dataList = sline[1:]                                  
        dataString = ','.join(dataList) 
        typestring1 = ','.join([x.strip() for x in dataString.split(",")])   

       if ' Object' in sline[0]:
        objectList = sline[1:]
        objectstring = ','.join(objectList)
        namestring1 = ','.join([x.strip()for x in objectstring.split(",")])
                   
writeString = (typestring1 + "," + namestring1+ ","+ "\n")
outfile.write(writeString)



outfile.close()
infile.close()
```

I'm new to python and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jake, welcome! Good question and good coding so far :) Can you share a larger example of your file? Some questions I have so far, not knowing exactly what your input looks like? 1) Does that file/format have a name specification (I see "DMP" but can only find "Windows dump" file, which that does not appear to be. 2) Why are skipping the first line of the file, `for line in lines[1:]`? 3) Is it always a block of 4 lines that starts with `Object :`?

Comment: Hi Zach, 1) that file format is just a text file, from a microcontroller memory dump; a larger example would be something like:
` Object : Info1
   Type : Info2
   LastChange : INFO3
   DeviceId : INFO4
EndObject

 Object : Info5
   Type : Info6
   LastChange : INFO7
   DeviceId : INFO8
EndObject `

This format repeats for hundreds of repetitions (with the same first column, but different info)

2) am i skipping that first line? (how can i tell?)
3) its always a block that starts with `Object :` and ends with `EndObject`

Forgive me if my formatting here is trash

Comment: Please put that larger example in the question, and show enough to say, "this is what two rows worth of data looks like".

Comment: That should show it a bit better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for a parser for the format but couldn't find the format for the input you're showing.  I'd take some time to make sure there isn't already a "Python parser for microcontroller memory DMP file".  You know the context better than me, so maybe your search will be more fruitful.

In the meantime, given your sample, **input.txt**:

```
 Object : Info1
   Type : Info2
   LastChange : INFO3
   DeviceId : INFO4
EndObject




Object : Info5
   Type : Info6
   LastChange : INFO7
   DeviceId : INFO8
EndObject
```

Here' an end-to-end solution that can read that sample and convert each "block" of object data into a CSV row.

The big point to stress is breaking down these kinds of problems into as many discrete steps as possible, like below:

1. Filter the DMP file to make sure you have at least a colon (`:`) in the line to parse into a value (or more specifically, just `Type :`)
2. Parse the filtered lines and prove you have found all your blocks
3. Convert the lines in each block into a row (that you can pass to the **csv** module's **writer** class)
4. Write your rows as CSV

```py
import csv
import pprint

filtered_lines = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('Object') or line == 'EndObject':
            filtered_lines.append(line)
            continue
    
        # Keep only Type
        if line.startswith('Type :'):
            filtered_lines.append(line)
            continue
    
        # or, keep any line with a color
        # if ':' in line:
        #     filtered_lines.append(line)
        #     continue

        # at this point, no predicate has been satisfied, drop line
        pass  # redundant, but poignant and satisfying :)


all_blocks = []
this_block = None
in_block = False
for line in filtered_lines:
    # Find the start of a "block" of data
    if line.startswith('Object'):
        in_block = True
        this_block = []

    # Find the end of block... 
    if line == 'EndObject':
        # save it
        all_blocks.append(this_block)

        # reset for next block
        this_block = None
        in_block = False

    if in_block:
        this_block.append(line)

print('Blocks:')
pprint.pprint(all_blocks)

# Convert a list of blocks to a list of rows
all_rows = []
for block in all_blocks:
    row = []

    # Convert a list of lines (key : value) to a "row", a list of single-value strings
    for line in block:
        _, value = line.split(':')
        row.append(value.strip())
    
    all_rows.append(row)

print('Rows:')
pprint.pprint(all_rows)

# Finally, save as CSV
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(all_rows)
```

When I run that against that input, I get:

```
Blocks:
[['Object : Info1', 'Type : Info2'], ['Object : Info5', 'Type : Info6']]
Rows:
[['Info1', 'Info2'], ['Info5', 'Info6']]
```

and the final, **output.csv**:

```
Info1,Info2
Info5,Info6
```

Comment: Running that threw me this error:
line 37, in <module>
    _, value = line.split(':')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

perhaps an issue with file size? (this file is rather large)

Comment: That line was coded-up based on your example, where there's only one colon (`:`) per line. That error means there are more than one colon. Wrap that line in a try/except and print the line from the block that has more than one colon, or just search your input text, and figure out how to split when there are more than one colon. Look at `lsplit()` and `rsplit()` and play around with them and their `maxsplit` option.

Comment: Figured out the max split, set that to 1, and that covered for some time formatting that was in the file; I did however, find some lines that do not have any of the separators in them and was curious how I would handle those?

And is it possible to select say just the 'Type' and output just that's value? I tried an If statement but it seems to not output anything (even the print statement I'm using to test it is showing nothing)

Comment: For filtering by 'Type' only, I'd add this, `if 'Type' not in line: continue` (probably good or even necessary to type that on two lines), under `for line in block:`... the loop will skip over any line that **_doesn't_** have the string 'Type' in it and not even try to split. The same pattern can be applied for filtering out "no-colons", `if ':' not in line: continue`.

Comment: @Jake, I rethought the approach to filtering and updated the code. More than anything, I hope you're getting a "feel" for how to iterate your input and keep certain lines, drop others, and know *where* in a block you are as you're parsing/iterating it.

Comment: thank you so much for explaining this out to me so thoroughly and for commenting so thoroughly on the code to allow me to actually follow along with what's happening. Still have a lot of new syntax to learn, but the time you took now will for sure help me to understand how to manipulate python;